# A holomorphic function whose image is contained in the unit circle is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a way to proof this without using that holomorphic functions are open mappings. Is there a very basic approach?

I'd appreciate any hint :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lvert f(z)\rvert = 1$ for all $z\in \Omega$, then $z \mapsto \overline{f(z)}$ is also holomorphic on $\Omega$.